# Android - Google login with OAuth 2.0

Tags: android, api, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-play-services

In Android's sample app (that's provided with google play services) for google login, they are using this SCOPE - "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
and this end point - "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="

While I was implementing it I came across [this document](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2LoginV1)  which (I think) states that this scope/endpoint is depricated:

> Important: Google has deprecated the early implementation of OAuth 2.0 for login that is described in this document but will maintain it and keep it available for backward compatibility. If your app uses OAuth 2.0 login (early version), you might consider either switching to Google+ Sign-In or changing your existing userinfo endpoints and scopes as described in migration timetable. For instructions, see Migrate or update OAuth 2.0 login.

Since I don't want to limit my audience to Google+ users, I want to update the OAuth 2.0 login, but I don't know how to do that. I completely lost in google api documentations.
I saw this endpoint somewhere - https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
but don't know how to use it and if I should change the scope.. And I also didn't understand if it is a regular google login or google+ login (since it has the word "plus" in the path..).

**I need an updated example/tutorial for google login.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ Signin *does* use OAuth 2.0. I believe by OAuth 2.0 Login, you are referring to [Open ID Connect](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect). That link includes sample code as well as an strong overview on the whole OAuth flow.

[Google+ Signin](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) is still a perfectly valid option of authentication though. Signin works for any Google account, whether or not you use Google+ does not matter (unless you actually need Google+ user information). It's also, possibly, the easiest way to implement OAuth, as you can get away with just integrating the button (using the code provided) and it will suffice for most applications.

Comment: So the scope and url that they are using in the sample app (specified in my question) are up to date? And i'll add google+ as well but not instead..

Comment: I believe the deprecated scopes you are referring to are the userinfo scopes. Those scopes may be deprecated, but they can still be used as backwards compatibility on them has been preserved. There are other scopes that have gotten deprecated from older versions of OAuth, but those are part of other APIs. The scope and endpoint in your post should be fine to use.